# how to find tomcat server system information using java code?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

i am developing web application and i host it in tomcat server. my requirement is client system wants to know the ip address of the system where the tomcat server located in a network.Before make any request to the server using java.or any possible to set default ip address for the tomcat server.and how can i use the default ip address to make a request if system ip and tomcat ip are different.

Comment: Where is the server is running, the client must know,

Comment: @anish server running in local area network.i need to find ip address of the server system before making request

Comment: if you know the host name , you can ping the hostname to get the IP address

Comment: @anish can you send some use full links to do that. because i am new to this.how can i find host name and how to ping that to get ip address using java code

Comment: if you are using, Windows type ipconfig, if you are using Linux type ifconfig on the command to get the ip address of the server where tomcat is running

Comment: @anish i need to know the ip address of the system where tomcat is running from the client machine using java code before make a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question right. So the server is running in a local area network and your client software does not know which address/ip to connect to? You could add a [multicast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) server to your servers app and a multicast receiver to your clients. The server will send a boardcast packet frequently to a specified boardcast address/channel, i.e. 203.0.113.0.

Once your client starts, it will receive the boardcast packet send by the server, as long as he is connected to the same channel. The packet is containing the servers address. You can than use that address to connect to the server.

**Update**

This is a very simplyfied example of a sender, receiver and a constants class to share the settings. It sends a String (Server is here) as packet data, but in a real world application, you should create an object serialize it at the server and deserialize it at the client. That object could hold more information about the server an could be verified at client side.

Server/Client side shared code:

```
public final class MulticastConstants {
 public static final String MULTICAST_PACKET_DATA = "Server is here!";
 public static final String MULTICAST_CHANNEL = "230.0.0.1";
 public static final int MULTICAST_PORT = 8881;
 public static final int MULTICAST_PACKET_SIZE = MULTICAST_PACKET_DATA.getBytes().length;
}
```

Server Side code:

The sender is a WebListener and will start and stop with your application.

```
@WebListener
public class MulticastSender implements ServletContextListener {

private MulticastSocket socket;
private boolean running = true;
private Thread mcss;

public MulticastSender() {
    System.out.println("New " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    try {
        socket = new MulticastSocket(MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_PORT);
        mcss = new MulticastServerThread();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating MulticastSender: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Starting " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    mcss.start();
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Stopping " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    this.running = false;
    socket.disconnect();
    socket.close();
}

private class MulticastServerThread extends Thread {

    public MulticastServerThread() {
        super("MulticastServer");
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Start sending multicast packets ...");
        while (running) {
            System.out.println("Sending multicast packet ...");
            try {
                byte[] dataBuffer = MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_PACKET_DATA.getBytes();
                InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_CHANNEL);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(dataBuffer, dataBuffer.length, group, MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_PORT);
                socket.send(packet);
                System.out.println("Packet send ...");
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error sending multicast packet: " + e.getMessage());
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}
}
```

Client side code:

The client only receives a single packet for simplicity. You might create a thread to not to freeze your clients gui.

```
public class MulticastReceiver {

private MulticastSocket socket;
private InetAddress address;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new MulticastReceiver();
}

public MulticastReceiver() {
    System.out.println("Starting MulticastReceiver ...");
    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByName(MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_CHANNEL);
        socket = new MulticastSocket(MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_PORT);
        socket.joinGroup(address);

        DatagramPacket packet;
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[MulticastConstants.MULTICAST_PACKET_SIZE];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            System.out.println("Waiting for packets ...");
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println("Received a packet (" + packet.getLength() + " bytes) ...");
            // deserialize packet.getData() to your own object (for simplicity a String is used) ...
            // check if type and serialVersionId are ok, otherwise dispose packet ...
            System.out.println("Server is located at: " + packet.getAddress());
            socket.close();
            // connect to server ...
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to host \"" + address + "\": " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error initializing: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Tested on Glassfish 4, hope that helps.

Comment: can you share some more links